Question on completeness of a measure
The top answer to this question states that

Complete just means that if $A$ is a measurable set with $\overline{\mu}(A)=0$, and $B\subset A$, then $\overline{\mu}(B)=0$ also.

However, the definition that I am aware of is:

A measure space $(X,\mathcal A, \mu)$ is complete if whenever $E\in \mathcal A$ satisfies $\mu(E) = 0$ and $F\subseteq E$, then $F\in \mathcal A$.

Moreover, if $A$ is a measurable set with ${\mu}(A)=0$, and $B\subset A$, then ${\mu}(B)\leq \mu(A)=0$ (by monotonicity) for any measure $\mu$!
Isn't the first statement simply the wrong definition? If not, where am I wrong?

Why? The two definitions are very much equivalent. Why do you feel the first one is wrong? (I’m not entirely sure about what you meant in your “moreover” part. But assuming I’m not misunderstanding, your error lies in implicitly assuming $B$ is measurable, as otherwise $\mu(B)$ does not make sense in the first place.)

Suppose $\mu$ is any old measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $V$ is a Vitali set. Is ${0} \times V$ necessarily measurable? (Example from the Wikipedia plot summary.)

@BrianTung if indeed $\mu({0} \times \mathbb R) = 0$, then does that result not follow simply by monotonicity?

@DavidGao That makes sense! I see my error now: implicit in the first definition is that $\overline\mu(B)$ is defined and takes value $0$.

@BrianTung Thank you for your response and the reference. I had already seen this, but Wikipedia uses the second definition I stated so I was unsure what to do with that example. Nevertheless, I realise my oversight now.

@kiston Indeed, that’s why the first definition implies the second. Monotonicity is why the second definition implies the first.

@DavidGao Thank you for your help. If you restate the above as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

As requested by OP, here are my comments, re-written into an answer:
In the “moreover” part you wrote down, the error is that you have implicitly assumed $B$ is measurable, as otherwise $\mu(B)$ does not make sense in the first place. And, this is exactly how the first definition implies the second - by asserting $\bar{\mu}(B) = 0$, there is an implicit requirement that $B$ is measurable. That the second definition implies the first follows from monotonicity of measures, as you have more or less already observed.
